# Command from Debian installation manual not working

Tags: debian, system-installation, usb-drive

I need to install Debian 10 from a USB stick (new computer doesn't have a CD/DVD drive). I'm in a neighbor machine with an Ubuntu 18 derivative. The [Debian installation manual](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.en.html) says:

> The CD or DVD image you choose should be written directly to the USB
>   stick, overwriting its current contents. For example, when using an
>   existing GNU/Linux system, the CD or DVD image file can be written to
>   a USB stick as follows, **after having made sure that the stick is
>   unmounted**:
>
> ```
> cp debian.iso /dev/sdX
> sync
> ```
>
> ## Important
>
> **The image must be written to the whole-disk device and not a
>   partition, e.g. /dev/sdb and not /dev/sdb1**. Do not use tools like
>   unetbootin which alter the image.

1) It tells me to unmount the disk before copying.

2) It tells me to copy to the device, not to any partition.

Of course, when I unmount the usb stick, /dev/sdb1 goes away, and all I have left is /dev/sdb. However, when I try

```
cp debian.iso /dev/sdb
```

I get an instant error

```
cp: não foi possível criar arquivo comum '/dev/sdb': Mídia não encontrada
```

Sorry, my system is in Brazilian Portuguese. The above sentence means

```
cp: could not create common file '/dev/sdb': Media not found
```

I have tried the following command

```
dd if=debian.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

but the usb stick wasn't recognized by the new PC (maybe UEFI problem?). (In both commands above, I've used the real filenames instead of debian.iso.)

I have searched for the `hd-media/boot.img.gz` file, but none exists (nor the directory `hd-media`, nor the `boot.img.gz` file, in neither `debian-10.1.0-amd64-netinst.iso` or `debian-10.1.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso` distributions.

Am I doing something wrong? Or Debian manual has some mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the "Media not found" message I think you may be ejecting the device rather than unmounting the filesystem.

Are you sure you're unmounting the filesystem (right) or ejecting the USB (wrong)?

Comment: Thank you! I was ejecting rather than unmounting. But when I finally unmounted, `/dev/sdb1` didn't disappear. It was disappearing when I ejected.

Comment: @Rodrigo yeah, `/dev/sdb1` should still be there after unmount (but not eject).  As you observed. (I struck that sentence from roaima's answer)